# SQL - only increment ROW_NUMBER() on specific values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have the below table and am trying to add a column using row number (partitioning by the product and ordering by the contract start date) which will only increment when the contract_status_id is not 4. If the contract_status_id is 4, it should show as -1

So the column for the below would show as

```
1,
2,
-1,
3,
```

[image]

What would be the best way of achieving this? My existing code looks like the below.. but this is as far as my row number knowledge goes!

```sql
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.product ORDER BY a.contract_start_date ASC)
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I think you'll need to query what you have again, using lag and if the previous statusid=4, then reduce your seqnumber by 1

Comment: @Nathan_Sav -- that would not work -- what if there is more than one with id of 4 -- see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you could do this. You could use `ROW_NUMBER` to start with, but you'd need to partition on the contract status with an `IIF`:

```sql
CASE Contract_Status_ID WHEN 4 THEN -1
     ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product, IIF(Contract_Status_ID  = 4,1,0) ORDER BY Contract_Start_Date)
END
```

You could, alternatively, use a conditional `COUNT`:

```sql
CASE Contract_Status_ID WHEN 4 THEN -1
     ELSE COUNT(CASE WHEN Contract_Status_ID != 4 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Product  ORDER BY Contract_Start_Date)
END
```

Comment: that conditional count is perfect.. so simple thank you

Comment: `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` would be wise, it's better performance and if `Contract_Start_Date` has duplicates then it's also more correct

Answer (score 1):

First you need a column to indicate the status (table x).  Then you get the row number for the ones you care about via partition (table z).  Finally you fix the values to match what you need.

```
SELECT -- all the stuff
  CASE WHEN z.c_status = 1 THEN val ELSE -1 END as final_result
  FROM (
    SELECT -- all the stuff
      Row_number() OVER ( partition BY x.product,x.c_status ORDER BY x.contract_start_date ASC ) as val
    FROM (
      SELECT -- all the stuff,
        CASE WHEN contract_status_id=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as c_status
      FROM tableyoudidnotname
    ) x
  ) z
```

Answer (score 0):

[Larnu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72886668/1592756) is definitely the "elegant" way to go, but if someone deals with a similar issue and works with a SQL Server version prior to 2012 (when the support of the `ORDER BY` clause was added for the aggregation functions), a `UNION` also does the trick:

```
SELECT Product, Contract_ID, Contract_Status_ID, Contract_Start_Date,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY Contract_Start_Date) 
Contract_Seq_Number
FROM table
WHERE Contract_Status_ID != 4
UNION
SELECT Product, Contract_ID, Contract_Status_ID, Contract_Start_Date,
       -1 Contract_Seq_Number
FROM table
WHERE Contract_Status_ID = 4
ORDER BY Product, Contract_Start_Date, Contract_Seq_Number
```